# Pyspark-Mongo missing some fields

Tags: python, mongodb, pyspark

So I am trying to read a collection form MongoDB into spark using mongo-spark connector, however some of the fields within the docuemnts are missing, Has anybody encountered this problem before ? If yes what's the solution ?

Following command I am using to read MongoDB collection:

```
orders = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource") \
        .option("uri" , "mongodb://127.0.0.1/company.orders") \
        .load()
orders.select('missing_field').limit(10).collect()
```

Example document:
a) Example document -

```
{
    "_id" : "0000-10001",
    "_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-03T22:47:47.000Z"),
    "total" : 64.96,
    "subtotal" : 64.96,
    "user_email" : “abc@gmail.com"
}
```

I can read all the fields except user_email

Comment: So, you're saying that some documents within the collection have missing fields. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?  identifying which fields are missing ? You could elaborate further by a) including an example document , and b) stating the expected goal that you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @WanBachtiar I just edited my question to answer a) and b)

Answer (score 2):

> however some of the fields within the documents are missing

By default the [MongoDB Connector for Spark](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/) infers a relational schema from a set of documents [randomly sampled](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) from the underlying collection. It sounds like the 'missing' field `user_email` is most often a NULL in MongoDB, causing the Spark connector to not able to create a data type mapping for it.

However, you can manually declare a schema, instead of using the auto sampling based schema map. For the [Python Spark API](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/python-api/), you can declare a schema with an example as below:

```
schema = StructType([StructField("user_email", StringType(), True), 
                     StructField("total", StringType(), True])
dataframe = rdd.toDF(schema)
dataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```

Answer (score -1):

I updated my spark-mongo connector and it solved the problem.

Comment: Could you specify what version of the spark-mongo connector solved this problem?